# How can I restrict bashs read command to only accept numeric values?

Tags: bash

is there a way I can limit bashs `read` to only accept numeric input,
so when anything else then a number is added, the user gets promted again?

```
read -r -p "please enter 2 numbers: " number
```

Comment: It's called `while`

Comment: Check your variable `number` and prompt something. Or chop in your variable everything that is not a number.

Comment: What kind of "number"?  There's a lot of definitions to choose from (ranging from non-negative numbers in the range 0-255, right through to arbitrary-precision complex rational numbers).  And you might need to be specific about the radix (decimal, octal, hex etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop with a condition using a pattern:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset number
until [[ $number == +([0-9]) ]] ; do
    read -r -p "please enter a number: " number
done
echo $((number + 1))
```

You might need to be more precise (`@(0|@([1-9])*([0-9]))`) if you want to use the number directly, because e.g. `09` will cause an error, as it will be interpreted as octal because of the starting 0.

Comment: NICE, thanks for this one! Only thing I don't quite understand is, what does `unset number` do?

Comment: @nath, makes sure we didn't inherit an initial value for `number` through the environment, if a program that called us `export`ed it for some reason.

Comment: (Personally, I'd use a regex rather than an extglob -- so, for instance, `[[ $number =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ]]` -- or use `=` rather than `==` as a string comparison operator so as to be getting finger memory that won't lead you astray when writing software for a minimal `/bin/sh`; but there's a lot of personal preference there; nothing about this answer is *wrong* as it stands, except insofar as it depends on a bash new enough to have extglob on-by-default inside a test context).

Answer (score 0):

change all none numeric value to empty and check for length.

```
if [[ -n ${number//[0-9]/} ]]; then
    echo "please enter a numeric value!"
fi
```

Comment: What happens with mixed numbers and letters?

Comment: there is length . then there is non digit , so its different